# python: crash inside try statement, expected behaivour?

Tags: python, exception

I have had a similar problem in the past, python code crashing inside a try statement. The code fails because neither the file or the directory that it is trying to open exist. But as it is inside a try statement, i dont understand why the code breaks.

{To save any reader from spending too much time trying to understand the premise of the code. It is trying to find vertices for a region file, from;

a) a master file, if it doesnt exist or it is bad, try (b)

b) a file specific to its name, if it doesnt exist or it is bad, do (c)

c) to create a new one
}

p.s. The following code is inelegant and probably won't be the final solution to what im trying to do.

```
    try:
        x1,y1, x2,y2 = np.loadtxt('regions/master.reg')
        plt.plot([x1,x1,x2,x2,x1],[y1,y2,y2,y1,y1], c='k')
        plt.draw()
        if (raw_input('Master Acceptable? (y/n): ') =='n'): raise(NameError)
    except NameError:
        try:
            x1,y1, x2,y2 = np.loadtxt('regions/'+self.name[:-5]+'.reg')
            plt.plot([x1,x1,x2,x2,x1],[y1,y2,y2,y1,y1], c='r')
            plt.draw()
            if raw_input('Reg Acceptable? (y/n): ') =='n': raise(NameError)

        except NameError:
            quality = False
            while not quality:
                x1=int(input('x, top left: '))
                y1=int(input('y, top right: '))
                x2=int(input('x, bottom left: '))
                y2=int(input('y, bottom right: '))
                plt.plot([x1,x1,x2,x2,x1],[y1,y2,y2,y1,y1], c='r')
                plt.draw()
                if raw_input('Acceptable? (y/n): ') =='y': quality=True
```

And the error (just saying that the file doesnt exist)

```
File "pre_science.py", line 45, in crop
  x1,y1, x2,y2 = np.loadtxt('regions/master.reg')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 917, in loadtxt
  fh = np.lib._datasource.open(fname, 'rt', encoding=encoding)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/_datasource.py", line 260, in open
  return ds.open(path, mode, encoding=encoding, newline=newline)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/_datasource.py", line 616, in open
  raise IOError("%s not found." % path)
IOError: regions/master.reg not found.
```

So my question being, is this an expected behaviour?

Comment: Take off the NameError on your except's and see what happens.

Comment: Why are you raising a NameError when the user says that something isn't acceptable? Why an exception at all, and of all possible exceptions, why a NameError?

Comment: @user2357112 this is why it was inelegant, i thought i could force it to try different methods in most preferable order but in a manner that wouldnt break if it couldnt be executed. as to why i used NameError, because i still dont fully understand exception handling and it was an educated guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specifying in your try-except block that you're expecting a **NameError**, but you're getting an **IOError**.

By using

```
try:
    ....
except NameError:
    ....
```

you're handling only exceptions of type **NameError**. All other exceptions (in your case **IOError**) that are thrown up are not handled anywhere, thus crashing your code.

Remove the **NameError** after the expect or add additional expected errors in the following manner

```
try:
    ....
expect NameError, IOError:
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to catch only NameError. Make it to catch both IOError and NameError

```
try:
    ...
    ...
except (IOError, NameError):
    ...
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`NameError` is the wrong exception type, use `OSError`:

```
try:
    x1,y1, x2,y2 = np.loadtxt('regions/master.reg')
    plt.plot([x1,x1,x2,x2,x1],[y1,y2,y2,y1,y1], c='k')
    plt.draw()
    if raw_input('Master Acceptable? (y/n): ') =='n': raise OSError()
except OSError:
    try:
        x1,y1, x2,y2 = np.loadtxt('regions/'+self.name[:-5]+'.reg')
        plt.plot([x1,x1,x2,x2,x1],[y1,y2,y2,y1,y1], c='r')
        plt.draw()
        if raw_input('Reg Acceptable? (y/n): ') =='n': raise OSError()
    except OSError:
        while True:
            x1=int(input('x, top left: '))
            y1=int(input('y, top right: '))
            x2=int(input('x, bottom left: '))
            y2=int(input('y, bottom right: '))
            plt.plot([x1,x1,x2,x2,x1],[y1,y2,y2,y1,y1], c='r')
            plt.draw()
            if raw_input('Acceptable? (y/n): ') =='y':
                break
```

In general, `NameError` should not be used as user-generated exception, because a `NameError` indicates nearly always a programming error.

In the spirit of «don't repeat yourself» the restructured code look's like this:

```
from functools import partial
from itertools import cycle, chain

def input_rect():
    x1 = int(raw_input('x, top left: '))
    y1 = int(raw_input('y, top right: '))
    x2 = int(raw_input('x, bottom left: '))
    y2 = int(raw_input('y, bottom right: '))

for reader in chain([
        partial(np.loadtxt, 'regions/master.reg'),
        partial(np.loadtxt, 'regions/'+self.name[:-5]+'.reg'),
    ], cycle([input_rect]))
    try:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = reader()
    except (ValueError, OSError):
        pass
    else:
        plt.plot([x1,x1,x2,x2,x1],[y1,y2,y2,y1,y1], c='r')
        plt.draw()
        if raw_input('Acceptable? (y/n): ') == 'y':
            break
```